# how to delete til a char in the next lines.

Tags: vim

I have  the following text layout. and I want to delete from ON to the ";" I tried to use "dt;", but it said it can't find ";", looks like "t" only try to find the char in the same line, possible to find the next lines?

```
 INNER JOIN () a *cursor* ON f.StoreID = a.StoreID
                                  AND f.UPC = a.UPC
                                  AND f.type = 'tom' ;
...other text...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to search for it and delete up to it using `d/;<CR>`. (`<CR>` is carriage return: pressing the return/enter key) Using `d` with a search behaves like using `t` with `d`. It will delete up to that character (or word if using a search). This is the behavior you want. If you want to also delete the `;` you should use `v/;<CR>d` to select all of it and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `t`, `T`, `f` and `F` all only look at the current line.

Zach's answer is the correct way to do this with vanilla vim however there are several plugins that you could use if you don't wish to use search.

I'd recommend you take a look at [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak): Sneak is a minimalist, versatile Vim motion plugin that jumps to any location specified by two characters. Using sneak you would use `dz;<cr>` to delete to the next occurrence of `;`. This has the advantage of not leaving all other `;` characters highlighted.

The vim-sneak README also list a bunch of similar plugins.

Answer (score 0):

"dt;" is only usefull in one line.I don't think there is a way to do this unless you define a macro, which makes no sense , because you can't decide delete to which ";", next line or next next line .I think you type `D` with your cursor on `ON`, then move to nextline and type `dd`.Use simple cmd to compose a strong cmd.Just like the unix， keep it simple。

Answer (score 0):

I would add another option, using `easyMotion` plugin.

you can `d<leader><leader>f;` then choose which `;` you want to delete to. pretty handy.